# Repository Pattern in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework code-first via StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, repository-pattern, structuremap

I'm creating a web app using *ASP.NET MVC 3* and *Entity Framework 4.1 code-first*. I'm designing the project via *Repository Design Pattern*. I know how to implement *RDP* and *Generic RDP*. But my question is that ***using StructureMap is a good idea on this case***? Thanks to any idea and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, but structuremap is more related, imo, to the DI approach you will use than the Domain specific approach you will implement. 
I personally use AutoFac, but Structuremap is a also very good, you may want to consider also Ninject. All of them are really powerful and have a nice syntax to work with imo.

Comment: +1 Thanks to answer. I'm new to *Dependency Injection*. Which you would suggest to use in a big web app (a social networking site) between: *Structuremap*, *AutoFac*, and *Ninject* please?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you pick. Take the one you like the most. We all have our favorite (mine is autofac)

Comment: As stated in the  previous comment it's a matter of taste. I choosed autofac for my projects and I'm an happy coder ;)